# "binary '[' : no operator found

Tags: c++, file, vector, operator-keyword

I have two vectors of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> savestring{"1", "3", "2", "4"}; // some numbers
std::vector<std::string> save2{"a", "b", "c", "d"};      // some names
```

And I wish to reorder the latter based on the former, so that it ends up being `{"a", "c", "b", "d"}`. I tried this:

```
for (int i=0; i<savestring.size(); i++)
{
    savestring[i] = save2[savestring[i]];
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> "binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

What does this mean and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't index a string with a string.  You'll have to convert the strings to numbers first.

Comment: For the future, please read up on what a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) implies. We shouldn't have to guess what the types of your variables are, and I shouldn't have to dig through your comments to rewrite your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `savestring[i]` is a `std::string` whereas there should be an integer inside the square brackets in `save2[]`.  So, the solution is to first convert `std::string` to integer by writing a custom function.

So, change this to:

```
// Converts a std::string to an int
int ToInt( const std::string& obj )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << obj;

    int ret;
    ss >> ret;

    return ret;
}


for(int i=0;i<savestring.size();i++)
{
    savestring[i]=save2[ToInt(savestring[i])];
}
```

Don't forget to include `sstream` header by writing `#include <sstream>` at the top.

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesnt work..It says "error C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'"

Comment: That's strange. What datatype is `savestring`. It would be better if you showed us the whole code.

Comment: std::vector<std::string> savestring;

Comment: what is the definition of save2?

Comment: std::vector<std::string> save2;

Comment: @hornet07 No problem! :) Don't forget to accept and **upvote**.

Comment: You can construct a stringstream for a `std::string`, no need to stream it. Also, there's [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) so you don't have to write your own.

Comment: @Barry I required to convert from a string rather than to it.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Sorry, linked to the wrong thing before and ninja-edited it.

Comment: @Barry OK. But, this function requires at least C++11 and there's no sign that the OP was using a compiler supporting that.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving numbers, represented as strings. You need to convert them to number, before using as an arrays index.